# webstorm подчеркивает @@include

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, webstorm

Использую в WebStorm сборку gulp, а конкретно плагины gulp-file-include и gulp-autoprefixer. Есть две проблемы:

1. когда используешь @@include из плагина gulp-file-include происходит следующее:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. когда в gulp-autoprefixer используешь параметр grid: true, то перед grid'ами в конечном css файле ставятся префиксы, которые так же подчеркиваются красным:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить? Желательно не менять WebStorm на другую IDE

Comment: только из за этой строчки `@@include` ошибка вылазит? Без нее все норм?

Comment: Можно перейти на `SCSS` и `ts` и пользоваться штатными `include` которые понимает IDE.

Comment: @Nick, да только изза нее.

Comment: @nazarpunk действительно неплохая идея. вопрос что делать с scss и подчеркиванием гридов

Comment: Ничего, ведь в `.scss` файлах их не будет, они только в `.css` будут после сборки вэбпаком. Ну а для `.css` можно вообще проверки выключить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема с `-ms-grid-*` известна, проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-30738](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30738). сейчас единственное решение - отключить error highlighting для `.css`, установив Highlighting level в None с помощью [inspection widget](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.2/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#change-highlighting-level-for-file) в правом верхнем углу файла.

`@@include` не является валидным синтаксисом javascript, поэтому синтаксические ошибки в редакторе ожидаемы. Опять-таки, единственная возможность убрать подчеркивание - отключить highlighting

Comment: для js отличным вариантом будет сделать один файл для всех @@include, отключить в нем highlighting, а сам код писать в других. спасибо за ответ